# Spectral measure of the multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and consider the operator $T\colon L^2(X,\mu)\to L^2(X,\mu)$ given by $Tf(x)=\varphi(x)f(x)$, where $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded measurable function.

Is there any possibility to determine the spectral measure explicitly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The spectral measure of $T$ is the measure $E(\Delta)=1_{\Delta}(T)$, where $\Delta$ is any Borel set in the spectrum of $T$, and $1_\Delta$ is the characteristic function of $\Delta$.

In your case, $T=M_\varphi $. Using functional calculus, we have, for any bounded Borel function $g$ on $\sigma(T)=\text {ess ran}\,\varphi$, that $g(T)\,f=(g\circ\varphi)\,f$ for any $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$. Then
$$
E(\Delta)f=1_\Delta(T)\,f=(1_\Delta\circ\varphi)\,f=1_{\varphi^{-1}(\Delta)}\,f.
$$

So, for each Borel set $\Delta$, the projection $E(\Delta)$ is the multiplication operator by the function $1_{\varphi^{-1}(\Delta)}$.

Comment: how can you apply the functional calculus to show that $g(T)f = (g \circ \varphi) f$ ?

Comment: @beno An easy, but not rigorous explanation is the following. The equality obviously holds for any $g(t)=t^k$. Hence it is holds for any polynomial. Since polynomials are dense in $C([a,b])$ then the equality $g(T)f=(g\circ\varphi)f$ holds for any continuous $g$. Then for any Borel set $A\subset[a,b]$ its characteristic function can be uniformly approximated by continuous, hence this equality holds for any characteristic function $g$. Since linear span of this characteristic functions is dense in the space of bounded Borel functions, then this equality holds for any bounded Borel function.

Comment: What is the exact measure coming from the spectral projection that you have showed? Is it primary measure $\mu$ that we have started with?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exact measure".

Comment: @Phibetakappa: on a quick search, you can check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557459/22857), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321391/spectrum-and-point-spectrum-of-a-multiplication-operator), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220314/spectrum-of-simple-multiplication-operator-on-l20-1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787066/spectrum-of-multiplication-operator), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036373/spectrum-of-multiplication-operator-t-in-c0-1).

Comment: Sir another question $:$ What do you mean by $1_{\Delta} (T)\ $?

Comment: It's the Borel Functional Calculus.

Comment: How do you know that $\text {ess ran}\ \varphi \supseteq \text {ran}\ \varphi$ so that $g \circ \varphi$ makes sense?

Comment: It's irrelevant, because we are looking at things in $L^2(X,\mu)$. By definition, $\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{ran}\varphi\setminus\operatorname{ess ran}\varphi)$ is a nullset, so what we do at those points does not matter.

Comment: If there are uncountably many such elements which are in the range but not in the essential range can we still conclude the same? Because every measure is countably additive or subadditive. Things are getting complicated if one has an uncountable. We know that for each $\lambda \in \text {ran}\ \varphi \setminus \text {ess ran}\ \varphi$ we have an $\varepsilon_{\lambda}\gt 0$ such that $\mu ((\lambda - \varepsilon_{\lambda}, \lambda + \varepsilon_{\lambda})) = 0$ and hence in particular $\mu (\{\lambda\}) = 0.$ How does it imply the set you mentioned is a $\mu$-null set if it's not countable?

Comment: It's an open set, so it's a countable union of intervals. Fix one interval; it's a countable union of compacts. Fix one compact. Cover it with uncountably many of your $(\lambda-\varepsilon_\lambda,\lambda+\varepsilon_\lambda)$, and take a finite subcover.

Comment: Oh! Get it now. Many many thanks for your kind help. One last question how do I show that $\int t\ dE = T\ $? I tried by approximating $t$ by a sequence of simple measurable functions $s_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k_n} a^{n}_i \mathbb 1_{\Delta_i}.$ Then for any $f \in L^2(\mu)$ we have $$\left ( \int_{X} s_n\ dE \right )f = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k_n} a^{n}_i \mathbb 1_{{\varphi}^{-1} (\Delta_i)} f.$$ How do I show that $\int_{X} s_n\ dE$ converges to $T$ in norm as $n \to \infty\ $? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean proving the Spectral Theorem, or you mean showing that $E$ is the spectral measure for $T$?

Comment: Sir I wanted to know that why $E$ is a spectral measure for $T.$ I know spectral theorem for self-adjoint and normal operators.

Comment: This possibly depends on how you define the integral against a spectral measure. But you have $$
E(\Delta)=\int_{\sigma(T)}1_\Delta(t)\,dF=F(\Delta).
$$ The first equality is the definition of $E$, while the second one is the definition of integral.

Answer (score 2):

Put for $M\in\mathcal B$, where $\mathcal B$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, $E(M)=A_{\mathbf 1_M}$, where, for $g\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$, $A_g\colon L^2\to L^2$ $A_g(f)=fg$. $E$ is a spectral measure, since

- $E(M)$ is a projection for all $M\in\mathcal B$: $$E(M)(E(M)g)(f)=E(M)(\mathbf 1_Mf)=\mathbf 1_M\cdot \mathbf 1_M \cdot f=E(M)f;$$
- $E(\emptyset)=0, $E(X)=Id$;
- If $M$ and $N$ are disjoint then $E(M)$ and $E(N)$ are orthogonal, since $$E(M)(E(N)f)=\mathbf 1_M\mathbf 1_N f=0=E(N)(E(M)f).$$
- If $\{A_n\}\subset \mathcal B$ are disjoint then $$E\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)(f)=\mathbf 1_{\bigcup_nA_n}f=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{A_n}f=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}E(A_n)(f).$$

Now check that $\int_f dE=A_f$ for all $f\in L^{\infty}$. $E$ is called the standard spectral measure.

Comment: I do not see why $\int_{f} dE = A_{f}$.

Comment: I tried to show that $<f,\int_{\sigma(A_{g})} dE f> = <f,A_{g}f>$. But somehow it did not work. I came to the expression

Comment: I tried to show that $<f,\int_{\sigma(A_{g})} dE f> = <f,A_{g}f>$. But somehow it did not work. I came to the expression $<f,A_{g}f> = \int_{X} |f(x)|^{2} g(x) d \mu$ and $<f,E(M)f> = \int_{g^{-1}(M)} |f(x)|^{2} d \mu$ and from this I could deduce that $d<f,\int \lambda dE f> = \int_{\sigma(A_{g})} \lambda d<f, E(\lambda)f>$ and from this I could deduce that $d<f,E(\lambda)f> = |f(x)|^{2} \chi_{g^{-1}(\lambda)}(x) d \mu(\lambda)$. How to go further ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the space $B([a,b])$ of bounded Borel functions. We will endow it locally convex topology. Let $M([a,b])$ be a Banach space of complex-valued Borel measures on $[a,b]$. For each $\mu\in M([a,b])$ we define a semi-norm
$$
\Vert\cdot\Vert_\mu:B([a,b])\to\mathbb{R}_+: f\mapsto \int\limits_{[a,b]}f(t)d\mu(t).
$$
The family $\{\Vert\cdot\Vert_\mu:\mu\in M([a,b])\}$ gives rise to some Hausdorff locally convex topology on $B([a,b])$. We will denote this space $(B([a,b]),wm)$.Consider $\mathcal{B}(H)$ with weak operator topology and denote this space $(\mathcal{B}(H),wo)$.

A continuous $*$-homomorphism $\gamma_{b,T}:(B([a,b]),wm)\to(\mathcal{B}(H),wo)$ such that $\gamma_{b,T}(id_{[a,b]})=T$ is called Borel functional calculus of operator $T$.

> **Theorem**
>   There exist unique Borel functional calculus $\gamma_{b,T}:(B([a,b]),wm)\to(\mathcal{B}(H),wo)$. Moreover this is contractive involutive homomorphism of involutive algebras which extends continuous calculus on $[a,b]$.

Denote $H=L^2(X,\mu)$. Since $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded measurable function then $T$ is a bounded selfadjoint operator. Hence $\sigma(T)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Since $T$ is selfadjoint then there exist some interval $[a,b]$ such that $\sigma(T)\subset[a,b]$. Now let $\gamma_{b,T}$ be the Borel functional calculus on $[a,b]$ then we can define spectral measure by the following procedure. For each Borel set $A\subset [a,b]$ we define its spectral measure $E(A)$ by equality 
$$
E(A)=\gamma_{b,T}(1_{A\cap[a,b]}).
$$
where $1_{A\cap[a,b]}$ is a characteristic function of $A\cap[a,b]$.