# Let $a\in C[0,1]$ and $A:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ where $A(x)(t)=a(t)x(t).$ Find $\sigma_{p}$, $\sigma_{c}$, $\sigma_{r}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $a\in C[0,1]$ and  $A:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ be a bounded linear operator defined by 
$$A(x)(t)=a(t)x(t)\qquad \forall t\in [0,1].$$
Find the point, recidual and countinuous spectrum, that is, $\sigma_{p}(A)$, $\sigma_{c}(A)$, $\sigma_{r}(A)$. The total spectrum is noted by $\sigma(A)$.

**My attempt:** I showed that
$$\sigma_{p}(A):=\left\{\lambda \left|\:  \exists U\subseteq [0,1] \mbox{ open  such that } f|_{U}=\lambda     \right.\right\}$$

Note that $A-\lambda I$ is not surjective iff $\lambda \in \mathrm{Imag}(a)$, therefore $ \mathrm{Imag}(a)= \sigma_{c}(A)\cup \sigma_{r}(A)$.

**My problem:** I have not been able to characterize $\sigma_{c}(A)$ and $\sigma_{r}(A)$.

**Remark:** It is important to clarify that I do not trust myself, so I would also like to know if the conclusions of my attempt are correct.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036373/spectrum-of-multiplication-operator-t-in-c0-1?rq=1

Comment: @Rigel In your link no make calculation of $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_r$.