# Spectrum and resolvent set of operator $ (Tx)(t) = (1+t^2) x(t) $ on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

> Operator $T : C[0,1]  \rightarrow  C[0,1]$ is defined by: $ (Tx)(t) = (1+t^2) x(t) , \forall  x \in C [0,1]$. We assume that norm on $C[0,1] $ is standard supremum norm. I have to find $\rho(T), \sigma_{p}(T), \sigma_{c}(T)  $and  $\sigma_{r}(T)  $.

The range of function $ 1+ t^2$, where $t \in [0,1]$ is $[1,2]$, so if $ \lambda \notin  [1,2]$, the inverse   $ (T - \lambda I ) ^{-1} $ exists and is bounded. It is defined on whole space $C[0,1]$, so the range of $ T - \lambda I $ is dense in $C[0,1] $. This means that the resolvent set $ \mathbb{C}  
 \setminus [1,2] \subset  \rho(T) $.

Now, if $\lambda \in [1,2] $,  there is unique number $t_{0} $ which gives $ 1+ t_{0} ^2 - \lambda = 0$. If we assume that $ x \in C [0,1]$ is a vector such that $ (T - \lambda I ) x(t)= (1+ t_{0} ^2 - \lambda) x(t)= 0, \forall t \in [0,1]  $, it follows from continuity of $x$ that $x = 0$. So, $T - \lambda I$ is injective.

I proved that $\operatorname{Range}(T  - \lambda I) $ is not dense in $C[0,1] $ because all functions that are in range satisfy this: $ y (t_{0})= 0$, so $\sigma_{c}(T) = \emptyset $.

I know that $\sigma_{p}$ is the set of eigenvalues, so $\lambda \in \sigma_{p}$ if $(T-\lambda I) ^ {-1}$ doesn't exist. We have already proved that $T - \lambda I$ is injective, but I wonder for which values of $\lambda$ is it non-surjective? (I am also confused if we need surjectivity at all when we consider eigenvalues). If I take arbitrary $ y \in \operatorname{Range}(T - \lambda I )$, then 
$x(t) = (T - \lambda I ) ^{-1} (y) = \frac{y(t)}{1+ t ^2 - \lambda }, t\neq t_{0} $. What is then $x(t_{0})$ and  is $x(t)$ continuous on $[0,1] $ at all?

Here is the solution of the task: $\sigma_{p} (T)=\sigma_{c} (T)= \emptyset$, $\sigma_{r}(T)= [1,2]$. Please help, at least give me some hint (I have recently started studying the spectral theory and this task would help me understand some basics better).

Comment: Good question. Small comment, the point spectrum is $\lambda$ such that $T-\lambda$ is not injective (hence has nontrivial kernel). The continuous and residual spectra have $T-\lambda$ injective but not surjective, which is why for $\lambda\in\sigma_r\cup\sigma_c$ we have $T-\lambda$ non-invertible, but $T$ has no $\lambda$ eigenspace.

Comment: In Kreyszig's Functional analysis it is said on page 371: that "The point spectrum or discrete spetrum $\sigma_{p}{T)$ is the set such that  $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}  does not exist (I suppose they mean if it's not injective?), But, on some websites and in some books they also verify if it's surjective, which confused me. Also, why is  T−λI not surjective for $  λ∈σr ∪ σc$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1036489/266110) $\sigma(T) = \{1+t^2: t\in[0,1]\}=[1,2],$ therefore $\rho(T)= \mathbb{C} \setminus [1,2].$

Suppose $\lambda \in \sigma_p(T),$ then there exists $0\neq x \in C[0,1]$ such that $Tx=\lambda x.$ Since $x \neq 0,$ there exists $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $x(t_0)\neq 0.$ Moreover $x$ is continuous, hence there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $t_0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in U.$ It follows that $$\lambda = 1+t^2 \; \forall\; t \in U$$which is absurd and hence $\sigma_p(T) = \emptyset.$

You have already shown $\sigma_c(T)=\emptyset$ and so $\sigma_r(T)=\sigma(T)=[1,2].$

Comment: Clear, thank you. Could you also please answer the following: The set $\sigma_{r}(T)$ consists of all $\lambda $ for which $(T - \lambda I)^{-1}$ exists, may be bounded or not, but it is not defined on dense subset. If that inverse exists, what would be the expression for  $(T-  \lambda I)^{-1} (y(t)) $, where $y(t) \in C[0,1]$?  And also, do we need to verify surjectivity or only injectivity when we talk about eigenvalues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user121 If $\lambda \notin [1,2],$ then $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}y(t)= \frac{y(t)}{1+t^2-\lambda}.$ Secondly, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T \iff$ $T-\lambda I$ is not injective. The surjectivity plays no role.