# Spectrum of operator: a question about an answer

Tags: functional-analysis

**Definition.** Let $X\ne\{0\}$ be a complex normed space and $T\colon\mathcal{D}(T)\to X$ a linear operator with domain $\mathcal{D}(T)\subseteq X.$ A $\textit{regular value}$$\;$$\lambda$ of $T$ is a complex number such that

$(R_1)\;$ $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\;$ exists;

$(R_2)\;$ $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\;$ is bounded;

$(R_3)\;$ $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\;$ is defined on a set which is dense in $X$.
The resolvent set $\rho(T)$ of $T$ is the set of all regular values $\lambda$ of $T$.

Let $X=C[0,1]$ and we define

$$T\colon X\to X\quad\text{as}\quad(Tf)(t)=g(t)f(t)\quad\text{for all}\quad t\in [0,1]$$ with $g\in C[0,1]$ fixed. I must study the spectrum of $T$.

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. In general the operator $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists iff for all $x\in X$ we have $$(T-\lambda I)x=0\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x=0.$$

We suppose that $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus g([0,1])$, then for all $f\in C[0,1]$ we have
$$[(T-\lambda I)f](t)= 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(t)[g(t)-\lambda]=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(t)\equiv 0.$$

Hence for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus g([0,1])$ exists $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$.

I have seen the following this answer to the problem
[click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1036725), but I can't understand why $\lambda\in\rho(T)$, that is I don't understand where the condition $(R_3)$ is.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $g$ is continuous, then $g([0,1])$ is the continuous image of a compact set and, hence, is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, if $\lambda\notin g([0,1])$, it follows that $\inf_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)-\lambda|=\epsilon > 0$. That guarantees that the inverse of $T-\lambda I$ is defined on all of $C[0,1]$, and is bounded by $1/\epsilon$. So $\lambda\in\rho(T)$ if $\lambda\notin g([0,1])$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that the fact that the operator is closed also matters, how can I show this?

Comment: @JackJ : For $\lambda\notin g([0,1])$, you have an explicit inverse of $T-\lambda I$ that you can directly see is defined everywhere and is bounded. That implies that $T-\lambda I$ is closed because of how the graph of $T-\lambda I$ and the graph of $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ are related.