# Spectrum and resolvent of an operator $(Ax)(t) = a(t)x(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $X = C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and define $A:X \to X$ where $(Ax)(t) = a(t)x(t)$, $a\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$

$C_0(\mathbb{R})$ the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $\lim_{\left | t \right |\rightarrow \infty }x(t) = 0$ with metric $\left \| x \right \| = max_{t\in R}\left | x(t) \right |$

It was our class example since this is not easy example but we don't have time to solve it. So we should solve it by ourself. Pls, can anyone solve it with a little description? Or give some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For invertibilty of $A-\lambda I$ consider the distance from $\lambda$ to the range of $a$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: see this q/a https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036373/spectrum-of-multiplication-operator-t-in-c0-1

Comment: not an exact duplicate because here the underlying space is $C_0(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @daw thank you!