# Spectrum of a multiplication operator in L^2

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I have following excercice:

> Let $X=\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $D=\{f \in
>  \mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R}) : \int |xf(x)|^2 < \infty \}$
>
> $A:D\subset X \rightarrow X$ $\; \; Af(x):=xf(x)$,
>     determine the
>   spectrum of A

I have shown, that $\sigma (A) =\mathbb{R}$ and that $\sigma_p (A)=\emptyset$
Now Im trying to determine the continous spectrum.

Let $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, then $(A-z)f \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ . Since these functions are dense in $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R}) $ it follows that Ran(A-z) is dense and therefore $\mathbb{R} \subset \sigma_c(A)$.
Is this correct?

kind regards

Comment: It's true that $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$, but you haven't shown that every $C_0^\infty$ function is in the range of $A-z$.  You should let $g \in C_0^\infty$ be arbitrary and construct an $f \in D(A)$ such that $(A-z)f=g$.

Comment: You are right, obviously., I wasnt able to construct the desired f, but i found an alternative proof.

Let $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $B_n:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-z| > \frac{1}{n}\}$
and let g be an arbitrary test function. Now $g \in D(A)$ and hence $1_{B_n}g \in D(A)$ and $1_{B_n}g \in Ran(A-z)$ because
$g_n:=1_{B_n}(x)\frac{1}{x-z}g(x) \in D(A)$ and $(A-z)g_n=g(x)1_{B_n}$ also     $1_{B_n}g \rightarrow g $ pointwise almost surely and by dominated convergence and Riesz in $\mathbb{L}^2$
Since $\overline{Ran(A-z)}$ is closed it follows that g is in there and therefore the claim. better now?

Comment: Yes much better.  You can post it as an answer so that this question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: out of curiousity, do you know how to construct the f, so that $(A-z)f=g$?

Comment: Trick question, you can't in general.  $(A-z)f$ will necessarily vanish at $x=z$ and so any $g$ which doesn't do so cannot be in the range of $A-z$.  In particular $C^\infty_0$ is not contained in the range.

Answer (score 1):

$A-\lambda I$ is invertible for all $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$. This is because
$$
         \frac{1}{x-\lambda }(A-\lambda I)f=f, \;\;\; f\in \mathcal{D}(A),
$$
and because $\frac{1}{x-\lambda }f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ for all such $\lambda$, with
$$
                (A-\lambda I)\frac{1}{x-\lambda}f=f.
$$
Therefore $\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, because $\frac{1}{x-\lambda}$ is a bounded multiplication operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ is in the spectrum because $\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)\ne L^2$ for any such $\lambda$, which can be seen by observing that the following is not in $L^2$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
                       e^{-x^2}\frac{1}{x-\lambda}.
$$

Comment: If $\sigma (A) = \mathbb R$ then it fails to be compact. But we know that spectrum of an operator is necessarily compact. What am I missing here?

Comment: @AntonioClaire : This particular solution does not require anything sophisticated. The solution is straightforward starting from basic principles. So why lob a grenade when a bb gun is sufficient?

Comment: Didn't you show that the spectrum of $A$ is the entire real line. But what I know is that the spectrum of any bounded operator is always a compact set but $\mathbb R$ fails to be compact. Doesn't it give us a contradiction? It will be very helpful if you clarify my query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AntonioClaire : Your observation shows you that multiplication by $x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is not bounded. And that is correct.

Comment: Oh I can see now. Since $\text {ess} \sup (x \mapsto x) = \infty.$

Comment: @AntonioClaire : That's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $B_n:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-z| > \frac{1}{n}\}$
and let g be an arbitrary test function. Now $g \in D(A)$ and hence $1_{B_n}g \in D(A)$ and $1_{B_n}g \in Ran(A-z)$ because
$g_n:=1_{B_n}(x)\frac{1}{x-z}g(x) \in D(A)$ and $(A-z)g_n=g(x)1_{B_n}$ also     $1_{B_n}g \rightarrow g $ pointwise almost surely and by dominated convergence and Riesz in $\mathbb{L}^2$
Since $\overline{Ran(A-z)}$ is closed it follows that g is in there and therefore the claim.